# Ambiguity in composition of functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Consider the simple student table,

```
mysql> select * from student;
+--------------+--------------+-------+
| student_name | joining_date | marks |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
| Anurag       | 2013-06-15   |    50 |
| Chandra      | 2014-07-12   |    65 |
| Dev          | 2014-03-25   |    80 |
| Gopal        | 2015-05-12   |    60 |
| Indra        | 2015-05-20   |    75 |
| Ram          | 2015-01-10   |    75 |
| Shyam        | 2015-01-10   |    50 |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to find:

> In which year, did maximum students joined the school?

So, it is similar to `max(count())` with a `group by`. But since SQL does not allow `max(count())`, I found an alternative to use `>= all`.

Here is the query and result:

```
mysql> select extract(year from joining_date) from student group by extract(year from joining_date) having count(student_name) >= all(select count(student_name) from student group by joining_date);
+---------------------------------+
| extract(year from joining_date) |
+---------------------------------+
|                            2014 |
|                            2015 |
+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I must get only 2015 but it generates two tuples.
When I removed `=` from `>= all`, I get the required result. But the maximum must to greater than all the elements right?

Another query for the similar question uses `>=`.

Consider the account table:

```
mysql> select * from account;
+----------------+-------------+---------+
| account_number | branch_name | balance |
+----------------+-------------+---------+
| A101           | Downtown    |     500 |
| A102           | Perryridge  |     400 |
| A201           | Brighton    |     900 |
| A215           | Mianus      |     700 |
| A217           | Brighton    |     750 |
| A222           | Redwood     |     700 |
| A305           | Round Hill  |     350 |
+----------------+-------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> I need to determine the branch that has the highest average balance

```
mysql> select branch_name from account group by branch_name having avg(balance) >= all(select avg(balance) from account group by branch_name); 
+-------------+
| branch_name |
+-------------+
| Brighton    |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when replacing `>=' by`>' I get,

```
mysql> select branch_name from account group by branch_name having avg(balance) > all(select avg(balance) from account group by branch_name); 
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: You have set of elements `{A1, A2, ... An}` By definition, if you are selecting maximum of that set, `max(Ai), i = 1..n` then it will be still an element of same set and therefore it can not be greater than all elements since then it won't belong to the original set. In short - your maximum is still __some element__ of the original set and therefore it will be equal to __at least one__ set element.

Answer (score 0):

## Year of max students

Return only the first found year with max students:

```
SELECT tmp.year
FROM (
   SELECT count(*) AS total, EXTRACT(year FROM joining_date) AS year
   FROM student
   GROUP BY year
   ORDER BY total DESC
) AS tmp
LIMIT 1;
```

Return all years with equal max students:

```
SELECT tmp.year
FROM (
   SELECT count(*) AS total, EXTRACT(year FROM joining_date) AS year
   FROM student
   GROUP BY year
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.total = (
   SELECT MAX(tmp.total)
   FROM (
      SELECT count(*) AS total
      FROM student
      GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM joining_date)
   ) AS tmp
);
```

I looked for ways to optimize this by reusing the subquery but found nothing that didn't make it much larger.

## Highest average balance

Return only the first found branch with highest average:

```
SELECT branch_name
FROM account
GROUP BY branch_name
ORDER BY AVG(balance) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Return all branches with equal highest average:

```
SELECT branch_name
FROM account
GROUP BY branch_name
HAVING AVG(balance) = (
   SELECT AVG(balance)
   FROM account
   GROUP BY branch_name
   ORDER BY AVG(balance) DESC
   LIMIT 1
);
```